# Loading big model from Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have a problem that my model is bit big (80M). As the downloading is slow, it will take 8-10 hours to download the model, according to my estimation. The problem is that when I load it statically in Unity("Forge" -> "Import Scene"), it gets expired soon, when the loading was only 2% completed.

Maybe it won't expire if I use 2-legged-authentication with the CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET, but I need to save it on the disk for building a prefab later. It seems currently "Import Scene" doesn't have the option of going with 2-legged-authentication. Does it mean that I need to somehow implement my own version of "Import scene" with 2-legged-auth? Any other suggestion?

Thanks.

[The authentication gets expired before the loading is completed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNioD.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your token is expired before completing the whole download procedure. As I know, there is an only one Bearer field on the [ForgeImportWindow](https://github.com/wallabyway/ARVRToolkit/blob/master/unity-src/ARVRToolkit/Assets/Forge/Editor/ForgeImportWindow.cs) to store the authorization info and it won't auto-refresh token now.

Each access token from the Forge OAuth service has a 30 ~ 60 mins lifetime. So, if your download procedure cannot be completed within 30 ~ 60 mins, it will be interrupted.

Unfortunately, Forge AR VR Kit doesn't support auto-refresh token currently. Apologies for any inconvenience caused. However, the Unity plugin is open source at http://forgetoolkit.com/#/ (see the GitHub icon on the top left corner), you can modify codes of the [ForgeImportWindow.cs](https://github.com/wallabyway/ARVRToolkit/blob/master/unity-src/ARVRToolkit/Assets/Forge/Editor/ForgeImportWindow.cs) to support auto-refresh token yourself.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you Eason for the hint. I found the token always gets expired in 60 min, and it seems this is the setting on Forge server side, which I can't change. Previously I thought it wouldn't expire if I use the 2-legged-authentication(with ID and secret) but actually it's the same. Now to make it support auto-refreshing, I have modified some code in the Forge AR/VR Toolkit(ForgeImportWindow, ForgeLoaderEngine, RequestQueue, and Requests) in my PC, I generated the token every 30 min and apply it in all types of requests in the queue, and now it's able to continue downloading after 60 min. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad that's helpful~ May I ask you a favor to mark this answer as accepted? This will help other Forge users who have the same issue to find the solution :)

Comment: Done. Thanks :-)